# R: navigating history and tab command completion do not work

Tags: r, readline

I have updated my R yesterday and the usual command line navigation in R stopped working. Specifically, tab key moves the cursor and does not compete a command, up-arrow key produces "^[[A", instead of recalling the last command, similarly for other keys. I cannot even edit a command as the left and right keys do not move the cursor.

My OS is Fedora 20 (everything is fine on my other machine with Debian).

Thank you for any hints.

Comment: Please keep on-topic. "If the language is statistically oriented (such as R, SAS, Stata, SPSS, etc.), then decide based on the nature of your question: if it needs statistical expertise to understand or answer, ask it here; if it's about an algorithm, routine data processing, or details of the language, then please refer to the collection of links to resources we maintain." There is nothing statistical about this question, and it's not about programming, so try R-help.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about the details of R use.

Comment: I suspect this is due to some configuation of your keyboard input rather than having anything to do with R. Why not add a tag for Debian? (If it were something to do with R you would need to post a lot of details that are obviously missing.)

Comment: Sorry for messing Nick. I'm going for the R help then.